# MobileFirst Analytics WL.Analytics.log in offline mode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using

```
WL.Analytics.log({"key" : 'value'});
```

to perform some analytics log in an iOS cordava app.

We are able to view the data using

```
http://localhost:9500/*/_search?q=module:%TestOldButtonPressedEvent%22%20AND%20timestamp:[2017-04-20%20TO%202017-04-20]
```

Question:

Yesterday, the mobileFirst and analytics was down for maintenance, user perform "TestOldButtonPressedEvent" using the iPad offline. (the app supports offline mode.

However, after the server is up today, there's no data in the elastic search result.

Does it means it doesn't keep the data in the iPad in offline mode and resend it to the analytics server once the server is up again?

Comment: MFP Server pumps the data into Analytics server only when the app makes a connect to MFP Server. When the application comes from the offline mode to online, the application implementation should take care of accumulating the data in the form of JSON key value pairs and use WL Analytics Log Api to push.